# .Net 4.5 Selfhost application issues

Tags: c#, .net, self-hosting

I have a windows service written in C# using Selfhost technology that act like a little server that can handle some webservice's requests.
This server need to be run continuosly and actually has no policy of autoreload or explicit memory cleanup. In some tests i have noticed that after few days (a dozen) it become "instable" (what i mean is that it starts to fail accesses to DB and the memory allocated by process drammatically increase).
What i would to ask is if it's a known issue of this technology that need to be reload or a clean up memory afert certainly time, or if i need to investigate better in my code.
I smell of memory leak but it seems too strange because i only use managed objects.

Comment: Caching? Is it a specific module that crash? What do you get out from the exceptions? I highly doubt it's a memoryleak, more of a caching problem.

Comment: Even with managed memory you can still have a leak... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx . "Selfhost technology" is stable. I have multiple windows services running using it.

Comment: Run memory profiler. I know ANTS and DotTrace - they are great but both commercial.

Comment: @Thomas Lindvall actualy there are no crash, but memory consumption amount about 1 GB  (the process allocate about 120MB when it start and then continuosly grow.
After that size (free memory is few MB) DB become to have transaction issue (i have log in eventviewer that say that db fail on Transaction promotion, restarting my program (free the memory) resolve the issue.
In my program there isn't explicit caching, is that a standard feature of selfhost?